# How to trigger a function which is inside another function

Tags: javascript, html

I have function running every second (**for clock**) .
I wanted to add sound to every tick tick....(second) but as function is running automatic (means no triggering is taking place) and when sound added produces an error

> **Error showing is :**
> Uncaught DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Know that it is not possible to play audio automatic .

So tried to create a `start` sound btn which play the `audio` but as second time (of clock) and don't match with audio . So there is a mismatch

I am trying to add that function(audio play) inside second(clock time) calculator .
Is this possible or not

[Link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40068112/16846346) but not able to find the solution

The code is as follows

```js
setInterval(clockRunner, 1000);

function clockRunner() {
  //Clock code goes here
  function trigger() {
    var audioElement = document.getElementById('audiotag1');
    audioElement.play();
  }
}
```

```html
<audio id="audiotag1" src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/Tick-DeepFrozenApps-397275646.mp3" preload="metadata" controls></audio>
<button onclick="trigger()">Start</button>
```

### Update

Added event listener inside the outer `function` but this way sound is playing once not every second .

One solution here can be adding another `setInterval` but this will again create problem of playing sound at different timing of clock's second

**Also it shows the same error in the console(mentioned above) until user clicks the btn**

```js
setInterval(clockRunner, 1000);

function clockRunner() {
  //Clock code goes here

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = new Date();
  setInterval(trigger, 1000);
  document.getElementById("triggerSnd").addEventListener('click', trigger)

  function trigger() {
    var audioElement = document.getElementById('audiotag1');
    audioElement.play();
  }
}
```

```html
<audio id="audiotag1" src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/Tick-DeepFrozenApps-397275646.mp3" preload="metadata" controls></audio>
<button id="triggerSnd">Start</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**Thanks for help in advance**

Comment: The only place you can call `trigger` from is *inside* `clockRunner`. For what purpose do you have this inner function, and not instead have its code directly inside `clockRunner`?

Comment: Ohh... think that solution can be calling event listener inside `clockRunner` for button and play sound . Thanks @connexo , I will try that way

Comment: @connexo tried another solution but that way sound plays only once on the click of btn . Solution for this can be adding another `setInterval` but this will create problem of playing sound at different time . Can you help me plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make use of some variables, you can control your code to perform like a clock. It's worth noting that there are two possibilities, either the clock has started or it has stopped.

The interval will run when you clicked to start and it will be cleared in stopping it. Here I can't notice any mismatch between the sound and the timer.

```js
var start = document.getElementById("triggerSnd")
var audioElement = document.getElementById('audiotag1')
var demo = document.getElementById('demo')
var interval, isMuted = true

// The second argument of addEventListener should be a function
// that receives an argument 'event'

clockRunner();
clock(); // call firstly
setInterval(() => clock(), 1000)
    
start.addEventListener('click', clockRunner)

function clock(isMuted){
  //Clock code goes here
  demo.innerText = new Date();
  audioElement.play();
}

function clockRunner() {
    audioElement.muted = isMuted
    start.innerText = isMuted ? "Start" : "Stop"
    isMuted = !isMuted
}
```

```html
<audio id="audiotag1" src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/Tick-DeepFrozenApps-397275646.mp3" preload="metadata"></audio>
<button id="triggerSnd">Start</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: It is because here clock is started with a trigger (same as that of sound) but I used trigger for sound only as wanted to let the clock run all the time . And again thanks for help (+1). Is there a way to let the clock remain automatic and it only audio run with trigger

Comment: And also can you tell about this `if(!hasStarted)`line as `hasStarted = false` so how we can use `!` not operator . What does this code making sense

Comment: Yes, you can start it muted and then unmute. How about it now? I omitted `controls` attribute to hide it showing toggling the icon

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me . Can you tell about `isMuted = !isMuted` and the above question about `if(!hasStarted)` line as `hasStarted = false` you used before this answer

Comment: Also why did you write `//call firstly` behind `clock()`

Comment: Because setInterval adds a delay at the first call. So I called clock() outside once to avoid it

Comment: Also Can you tell about `isMuted = !isMuted` and the above question about `if(!hasStarted)` line as `hasStarted = false` you used before this answer

Comment: One last thing : The error still shows up in console as mentioned in the question `Uncaught DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

Comment: `isMuted = !isMuted` negates the value of this variable (supposing it's boolean) and reassigns its value. Same applies to previoud `hasStarted`. For instance, if `isMuted` is true, then it changes to false. The logic is every time you click the start/stop button to toggle the value of isMuted. Once true, it doesn't play sound. Once false, it plays

Comment: Try adding `autoplay` tag to audio. If it does not work, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use)

Comment: Audio is playing after the click on `start` but until the button is clicked error is showing up every second and stops when btn is clicked . I think it is not possible to remove that but thanks for help . If you find anything that may help feel free to help : )

Answer (score 1):

I've changed my answer completely. Now I didn't need to use an event listener, just the proper API of [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) that audio uses. Note that I've add  `loop` attribute to tick's audio.

```js
var blast = document.getElementById("blast");
var tick = document.getElementById("tick");

var tickDuration, timeDiff, lastTime


tick.onloadedmetadata = () => tickDuration = tick.duration


timeDiff = 0.3 // max difference between sync, dont lower it or it will bug (can explain if u want)
lastTime = 0

blast.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
    let bct = blast.currentTime
  let tct = tick.currentTime
  let syncBlastTime = tickDuration - (tickDuration - bct%tickDuration)
  let diff = Math.abs(syncBlastTime - tct)
  lastTime = bct
  
  console.log(`Blast: ${bct} Tick: ${tct}\nSynced time difference (seconds): ${diff.toFixed(6)}`)
  if(diff > timeDiff) { // add this or it will bug the tick audio
        tick.currentTime = syncBlastTime
   }  
})

blast.addEventListener("pause", () => {
   tick.pause()
})

blast.addEventListener("playing", () => {
   tick.play()
})
```

```html
<audio id="blast" src="http://stream.arrowcaz.nl/caz64kmp3" controls="loop"></audio>
<audio id="tick" src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/A-Z_Vocalized-Mike_Koenig-197996831.mp3" loop controls='loop'></audio>
<br />
```

Comment: But as `sound` is inside clock `function` so when I trigger the `audio` it will play irregular with the speed of seconds needle

Comment: You can attach a `pause` event to clear it

Comment: I want to play sound every sound but when trigger with different `setInterval` there is irregularities in playing of sound . Know that `pause` can remove sound but I want to remove irregularities in playing of sound

Comment: I got it. Updated. Check it now if it solves your problem

Comment: Thanks for help(+1) . But one problem comes up the first click produces sound faster(first 2 clicks) and after that it plays alright . Can see in the updated question

Comment: I forgot to update and went lunch, lol. Now you can check

Comment: Thanks for replay and update . But can you tell in the above question context (taking it as example) , I have updated the clock code and an audio which run on clicking start but clock is running automatic . And there seems difference in seconds change(timer) and audio play can you tell in that view point